# How to make eslint work in git-hook pre-commit (it works only in terminal)?

Tags: git, eslint, githooks, eslintrc

I try to set up easy eslint check on pre-commit hook.

There is a folder with git repo and project-folders inside:

```
test3/
—.git
—project1/
——node_modules/
——src/
———js/
————1.js
——.eslintrc.json
```

I set up eslint locally and [eslint-config-standard](https://github.com/standard/eslint-config-standard):

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-config-standard eslint-plugin-standard eslint-plugin-promise eslint-plugin-import eslint-plugin-node
npm install --save-dev eslint
```

Create config .eslintrc.json:

```
{ "extends": "standard"}
```

Launch it in terminal - it works perfect:

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint src/js
```

Try to make git-hook, go to `.git/hooks`, rename `pre-commit.sample` in `pre-commit`. Remove all inner code and insert my own:

```
path="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
"$path/project1/node_modules/.bin/eslint" "$path/project1/src/js/"
```

Try to commit changes in js-file, and get error:

```
[notebook@NOTEBOOKs-MacBook-Pro project1 (master +)]$ git commit -m "T"
Oops! Something went wrong! :(
ESLint: 6.6.0.

ESLint couldn't find the plugin "eslint-plugin-import".

(The package "eslint-plugin-import" was not found when loaded as a Node module from the directory "/Users/notebook/Documents/Projects/test3".)
It's likely that the plugin isn't installed correctly. Try reinstalling by running the following:
npm install eslint-plugin-import@latest --save-dev
The plugin "eslint-plugin-import" was referenced from the config file in "project1/.eslintrc.json » eslint-config-standard".

If you still can't figure out the problem, please stop by https://gitter.im/eslint/eslint to chat with the team.
```

**It looks like local eslint doesn't see his own local plugins. How can i show it him? Where should i write correct paths to plugins?**

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue. In order to fix it, I needed to specify the directory containing the plugins in my git hook:

```
eslint --resolve-plugins-relative-to C:/Users/<Username>/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules $FILE
```

I don't know why it works differently between running the command manually and having the git-hook run it.